# Нужно создать таблицу с заданной последовательностью чисел t-sql

Tags: sql-server

Нужно создать таблицу в которую происходит запись последовательности чисел.  Числа нужно генерировать в пределе от задаваемого min к max с шагом = 1.

Решила через WITH, но забраковали результат. Нужно решить через SELECT, a не рекурсию. Идей, как это реализовать, нет.

ПС. Работаю на 2008-м сервере, где CREATE SEQUENCE использовать технически нет возможности.

Пример решения с WITH

```
DECLARE @Start_num int, @End_num int
SET @Start_num = :Start_num
SET @End_num = :End_num

;WITH Num_seq(Num)  AS
(
SELECT @Start_num
UNION ALL
SELECT Num+1 FROM Num_seq WHERE Num < @End_num
)
SELECT Num FROM Num_seq OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: тогда вам нужна опорная таблица в которой будет нужное кол-во записей или переклеить несколько раз саму с собой таблицу что бы на выходе получить нужное кол-во записей. вместо таблицы можно использовать несколько `select 1 union select 2 ...`. Но все эти решения не универсальны, потому что для произвольного End_num записей может не хватить

Comment: @Mike, вполне универсальны, главное, чтобы максимальное теоретическое значение было больше или равным максимальному значению для int ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример генерации последовательности от 0 до 9999:

```
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n)
ORDER BY 1
```

Можно расширить до любого разумного количества и ограничить выборку необходимыми переменными **min** и **max**

Comment: Спасибо! Этот вариант - оптимальный!

Comment: Неплохо было бы за него проголосовать в таком случае ;)

Comment: Голосую. Но репутация низкая(11 баллов) и не засчитывается (нужно от 15-ти)((

Comment: @TataSkliar в таком случае предлагаю принять ответ (зеленая галочка) это в дальнейшем поможет другим участникам ориентироваться в ответах и в том, какой именно ответ подошел автору вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

Есть классическая реализация такого запроса от Ицика Бен-Гана - автора множества книг по T-SQL.

Создается такая функция, из нее делается выборка:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- © Itzik Ben-Gan
----------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
             FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO
```

При необходимости можно не как функцией пользоваться, а как простым запросом.

Статья про данную функцию и ее создание: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers

Кроме того, есть еще несколько альтернативных вариантов, каждый из которых показывает разную производительность в разных ситуациях, но выбор из этих вариантов не особо нужен - если такая таблица нужна постоянно - лучше создать ее физически на сервере, заполнив один раз, если время от времени - производительность не слишком важна.

Comment: Благодарю. Интересный вариант. 

Таблица каждый раз создается новая на основании новых граничных значений и на разное кол-во строк, соответственно. Единственная стабильность - шаг мерой в единицу.

Comment: @TataSkliar, так в запросах легко отфильтровать только нужное количество записей. Смысл в том, что физическая таблица - это, как правило, самое малое время доступа, поэтому, если нужна производительность, лучшее ее и использовать.